# How to change the data type of embedded object - mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am having following document in the `mongoDB`. I want to change the `currentVisit` data type to `integer`

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5385e14f5caf98cc0712931c"),
    "location" : {
        "language" : null,
        "country" : "null",
    },
    "request" : [
        {
            "currentVisit" : "1401292066",
            "lastVisit" : "1401292066",
            "visitedTime" : "1401282894"
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Note

I had tried the following but it is not working.

```
 db.visits.find().forEach( function (x) { x.request.currentVisit = parseInt(x.request.currentVisit); db.visits.save(x);});
```

Any suggestion will be grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close but you need to loop the inner array as well

```
db.visits.find().forEach(function (x) { 
    for ( var i=0; i <= x.request.length; i++ ) {
         x.request[i].currentVisit = parseInt(x.request[i].currentVisit);
    }
    db.visits.save(x);
});
```

You probably want all of them really:

```
db.visits.find().forEach(function (x) { 
    for ( var i=0; i <= x.request.length; i++ ) {
         x.request[i].currentVisit = parseInt(x.request[i].currentVisit);
         x.request[i].lastVisit = parseInt(x.request[i].lastVisit);
         x.request[i].visitedTime = parseInt(x.request[i].visitedTime);
    }

    db.visits.save(x);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `request` field is an array, so you should iterate over it to change the value "currentVisit" field in each subdocument:

```
db.visits.find().forEach( function (doc) { 
    doc.request.forEach(function(subdoc) {
        subdoc.currentVisit = parseInt(subdoc.currentVisit); 
    });

    db.visits.save(doc);
});
```